# Tooltip is not showing at appended 'rect' on top of point/circle in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 line chart with a tooltip, I am facing a problem with a tooltip.

I have functionality, on click of points/circle I am appending `rect` to g, which is adding on top of the existing `rect` which has the tooltip functionality.

My tooltip is not coming at selected(rect) Graph Point.

```
g.append("rect")
      .attr("class", "overlay")
      .attr("id", "firstLayer")
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height)

      .on("mouseover", function(d) {
        focus.style("display", null);
        div
          .transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", 0.9);
      })

      .on("click", function(d, index) {
        let newXScale = newX ? newX : xScale;
        if (rect) rect.remove();
        rect = g
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", newXScale(d.startTime) - 12.5)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width", 24)
          .attr("height", height + 5)
          .attr("data", d.startTime)
          .style("fill", "steelblue")
          .style("opacity", 0.5);

        if (clickLine) clickLine.remove();
        clickLine = g
          .append("line")
          .attr("x1", newXScale(d.startTime))
          .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
          .attr("x2", newXScale(d.startTime))
          .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]))
          .attr("class", "focusLine")
          .style("opacity", 0.5);
      })
```

`rect` element is coming on top of the gm on hover of that tooltip is not coming, any suggestions on how to fix it ?

On mouse hover -
[image]

At selected Graph Point -

[image]

CodeSandbox link below - 
https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-dawn-82hxc

Please guide me what can be changed.

Comment: let me know if the question is not clear because I didn’t see any reply/query on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

on click of the `circle` you are appending another rectangle to g, which is adding on top of the existing `rect` which has the `tool tip` functionality

***Note: d3 js adds layer/shape on top of another which basically overrides the existing layer/shape functionality with the new layer/shape if they are in the same `position`***

To avoid that we have to draw the layers depends on their intended purpose and position.

***Solution for the above problem***

append background `rects` for `circle` you want to create with `opacity: 0`

```js
g.selectAll(".faaa")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("class", "faaa")
  .attr("id", d => "rect_" + d.id)
  .attr("x", d => xScale(d.startTime) - 12.5)
  .attr("y", 0)
  .attr("width", 24)
  .attr("height", height + 5)
  .attr("data", d => d)
  .style("fill", "steelblue")
  .style("opacity", 0);
```

append `firstLayer` `rect` which has the tooltip functionality so the background `rect` won't break the `tooltip` functionality

```js
g.append("rect")
  .attr("class", "overlay")
  .attr("id", "firstLayer")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)

  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    focus.style("display", null);
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", 0.9);
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    focus.style("display", "none");
    div
      .transition()
      .duration(300)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  })

  .on("mousemove", function() {
    var mouse = d3.mouse(this);
    var mouseDate = xScale.invert(mouse[0]);
    var i = bisectDate(data, mouseDate); // returns the index to the current data item

    var d0 = data[i - 1];
    var d1 = data[i];
    let d;
    // work out which date value is closest to the mouse
    if (typeof d1 !== "undefined") {
      d = mouseDate - d0.startTime > d1.startTime - mouseDate ? d1 : d0;
    } else {
      d = d0;
    }

    div
      .html(
        `<span>${parseDate(d.startTime)}</span>
        <span> Changes : ${d.magnitude} % </span>`
      )
      .style("left", d3.event.pageX + "px")
      .style("top", d3.event.pageY - 28 + "px");
    var x = xScale(d.startTime);
    var y = yScale(d.magnitude);

    focus
      .select("#focusCircle")
      .attr("cx", x)
      .attr("cy", y);
    focus
      .select("#focusLineX")
      .attr("x1", x)
      .attr("y1", yScale(yDomain[0]))
      .attr("x2", x)
      .attr("y2", yScale(yDomain[1]));
    focus
      .select("#focusLineY")
      .attr("x1", xScale(xDomain[0]))
      .attr("y1", y)
      .attr("x2", xScale(xDomain[1]))
      .attr("y2", y);
  });
```

append `circle` and add `click` functionality then change the `opacity` to highlight the background `rect`

```js
  g.selectAll(".foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("id", d => d.id)
    .attr("class", "foo")
    .attr("data", d => d)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return xScale(d.startTime);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.magnitude);
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
      return 6;
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      // change the opacity here
      d3.select("#rect_" + d.id).style("opacity", 0.5);
    })
    .attr("class", "circle");
```

Hope this solves the above problem...

Comment: Thanks jai, let me try this, this is working code pen, You can update the code if you can - https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-dawn-82hxc

Comment: I am trying to check how to get the closest rect, by doing Element.closest() but not getting.

Comment: I tried this also but it's not working  `d3.select(rect.node().closest('svg'));`

Comment: while creating `rect` add an aditional attribute `element-id` to that `rect` and assign `unique value in the data element` like `.attr('element-id', funciton(d){return d.unique_col;})`, while retrieving on click also try using `jquery selectors` for that `element-id` like `on('click', funciton(d){$('#firstLayer[element-id='+d.unique_col+']')})` and get the eement

Comment: I added `rect = g
          .append("rect")
          .attr("x", newXScale(d.startTime) - 12.5)
          .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width", 24)
          .attr("height", height + 5)
          .attr("id", "rect-element")
          .attr("data", d.startTime)
          .style("fill", "steelblue")
          .style("opacity", 0.5);` how to add unique value in data element, can you guide me please.

Comment: Jai, `.attr("element-id", d => d.col_name)` what is col_name here and what is element-id" attribute doing.

Comment: Can you help me fix this ? I have updated my code based on your suggestion but it's not working. https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-dawn-82hxc

Comment: made the necessary changes and updated here https://codesandbox.io/s/black-bush-syusc

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, I am trying to do the changes you suggested, https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-monad-xw9dw. still, some issues are there it seems, I will check.

Comment: Jai, I have one more question would you like to guide me - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60412324/in-my-d3-chart-appended-rect-is-not-coming-properly

Comment: please share the latest codesandbox link, I will look into it

Comment: I have resolved the issue, thanks, but now I am seeing some weird issue.  Can you please check this if you can help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60416561/my-chart-is-showing-some-red-point-circle-in-the-starting-of-the-y-axis-on-top

Comment: I do not have privilege to add comment there, but I can't reproduce the issue - please explain the scenario so I can help

Comment: It's ok not an issue, I will figure it out, Tha ks gain for help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208617/discussion-between-javascript-coder-and-jai).

Comment: Hi Jai,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63048007/how-to-reset-the-d3-selection-of-point

Can you help me with this query ? it's new question.